# Redirecting process output to a file per date

Tags: logging, stdout

I'm currently redirecting all my service's standard output (`stdout` and `stderr`) to a single file, by starting is as such:

```
java blablaargs &> service.out
SVCPID=$!
```

However, that file grows quite large. Is it possible, without changing the service program itself (perhaps via some filter command), to split the output by day?

Note: "Use a logging framework in Java" is not the droi... answer I'm looking for, sometimes important output just goes to `stdout`, out of my control.

Answer (score 1):

You should configure [logrotate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) to do this for you - that's it's job.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at something like cronolog  http://cronolog.org

It will do exactly what you ask for, splitting log files based on template, reading from STDIN.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using syslog (for `syslog-ng`'s filter and rotating capabilities for example), especially if you already use it in your system.

In order to catch `stdout` and `stderr` to syslog, you can pipe your program's output to `logger`, e.g. for example: (from https://blogs.oracle.com/chrisg/entry/redirecting_output_to_syslog)

```
my_script | logger -p local6.debug -t my_script 2>&1
```

see the [man (1) logger](http://linux.die.net/man/1/logger).